# ViewController popped immediately after been pushed in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I bounce in a quite weird issue. When I push a specific view controller for another one, the former get dismissed soon after being showed. When I push it fom the main View Controller, it stays put without any problems. I put breakpoints and the viewDidDisappear is in fact called just after the viewDidAppear.
By smell it look like the second view controller becomes nil in one way, but how is it possible if that is wired to the storyboard?
Has anyone got any idea about what could be the reason for the weird behavior? 
The main view controller and the first view controller are both in Swift, the pushed controller is still in Objective-c.
This is how I open the second view controller:

```
func didSelectRow(indexPath: NSIndexPath, from owner: DestinationsViewController){
    if let currentElement=DestinationsContentProvider.sharedContentProvider().stations[indexPath.row]{
        print("a \(indexPath.row) elemento \(currentElement)")
        let targetModel = currentElement.model
//NSLog(@"targetMetro:%@ targetPaletta=%@", owner.targetMetro, owner.targetPaletta);
        if ((targetModel != nil) && (targetModel!.myTraffic != nil)){
            targetModel!.segueExecute()
     }
 }
```

segueExecute is called on the model that is not dismissed. I put a breakpoint on the dealloc and it is never reached.

The only peculiar issue is that in the model I perform the segue on the main controller instead of the actual controller by this piece of code:

```
mapController.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowWaiting", sender:self)
```

Still the same behavior happens even if I manually push the controller by executing:

```
let mainStoryboard:UIStoryboard!
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad){
    mainStoryboard=UIStoryboard(name:"StoryboardiPad", bundle: nil)
} else {
    mainStoryboard=UIStoryboard(name:"MainStoryboard_iPhone", bundle: nil)
}
let controller = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Situation") as! StationSituation
controller.model=targetModel;
InArrivoHDViewController.sharedDetailController().navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

without using the segue construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by directly calling performSegue on the view controller rather than delegating it to the root controller. For some reason this delegation works if there is the same kind of view controller on the Navigation queue in which you are pushing the controller: I have this construct in another class and I just checked it actually work. Otherwise the effect is the weird one I experienced.

I think, but I may not be sure, that in Objective-c the situation was different.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether second view controller used for pushing is a property or not. If secondVC instance is created within the method in which pushing is done, secondVC will become nil after execution of the method.

Comment: Not quite, I added the code snippet triggering the segue.